# Too many open file while using numpy load

Tags: python, numpy

Hey i guys stuck in this error, i really need help:

> Error is: Too many open files.

```
        for i in data_files[:8]:
            try:
                data_temp = np.load(i)
                nat_queue += data_temp['nat_queue'].tolist()
                temp_radius = data_temp['temp_radius'].tolist()
                final_radius += data_temp['final_radius'].tolist()
                del data_temp.f
                data_temp.close()
                os.unlink(os.path.join('/tmp/rad_data', i))
            except:
                pass
```

when i run this code RAM(System Memory) increases linearly and after a while i got too many open files. 
what should i do..??

any help or suggestion would be appreciated?

Comment: except: pass isn't good practice, since you loose information on what is going on. Try printing the error - I would assume there is some issue with del data_temp.f - then the close statement would be skipped.

Comment: What happens to `nat_queue`, `temp_radius`, `final_radius`.. 
List take up a lot of space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the "Context Manager" mechanism when you call `np.load()` on multi-array files like this:

```
for path in data_files[:8]:
    with np.load(path) as arc:
        nat_queue += arc['nat_queue'].tolist()
        temp_radius = arc['temp_radius'].tolist()
        final_radius += arc['final_radius'].tolist()
    os.unlink(os.path.join('/tmp/rad_data', path))
```

This way, the archive of arrays `arc` will be closed.

By the way, if the inputs are large, you are doing yourself no favors by converting all the data to lists.  You could just append each loaded array to a list of arrays, then do `np.concatenate(list_of_arrays)` at the end to get a single large array from all the files' contents.

Comment: thanx for reply. your answer seems very logical, i will definitely try